# VB.NET InvokeMember method list

Tags: vb.net, list

I am using the HtmlElement's InvokeMember function and was wondering if there is a nicely formatted list of all the strings that can be passed into that function.

So far I know about these strings that can be passed into InvokeMember:
Click, Focus

Can somebody provide a link to a list of all strings that can be passed into the InvokeMember function or write them down?

Answer (score 0):

MSDN has the list of all the documentation for the classes in the .NET Framework.  Here is HtmlElement's documentation listing all of its members:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.aspx

Comment: Thx. I looked at the MSDN documentation fot HtmlElement. In the documentation for the method InvokeMember at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5b41b0d.aspx there is no information what values can be passed into the parameter methodName of the method InvokeMember. I checked the documentation on MSDN but I can't find this information.